# Parametric plot of solution of 2x2 diff. system in python, Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, odeint, parametric-equations

I've implemented a solution to the following system of equations

```
dy/dt = -t*y(t) - x(t)
dx/dt = 2*x(t) - y(t)^3

y(0) = x(0) = 1.
0 <= t <= 20
```

firstly in Mathematica and afterwards in Python.

My code in Mathematica:

```
s = NDSolve[
{x'[t] == -t*y[t] - x[t], y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, x[0] == y[0] == 1},
{x, y}, {t, 20}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 20}]
```

From that I get the following plot: [Plot1](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1401779758.jpeg) (if it gives a 403 Forbidden message please press enter inside the url field)

Later on I coded the same into python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = lambda t: t

def f(z,t):
    xi = z[0]
    yi = z[1]
    gi = z[2]

    f1 = -gi*yi-xi
    f2 = 2*xi-yi**3
    return [f1,f2]

# Initial Conditions
x0 = 1.
y0 = 1.
g0 = g(0)
z0 = [x0,y0,g0]
t= np.linspace(0,20.,1000)

# Solve the ODEs
soln = odeint(f,z0,t)
x = soln[:,0]
y = soln[:,1]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

And this is the plot I get:
[Plot2](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1401780840.png) (if it gives a 403 Forbidden message please press enter inside the url field)

If one plots again the Mathematica solution in a smaller field:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 6}]
```

he will get a similar result to the python solution. Only the axis' will be misplaced.

Why is there such a big difference in the plots? What am I doing wrong?

I suspect that my python implementation of the model is wrong, especially where f1 is calculated. Or maybe the plot() function isn't handy at all for plotting parametric equations as in this case.

Thanks.

ps: sorry for making your life hard by not slapping the images inside the text; I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Perhaps it's simply the automated scaling that Mathematica does different compared to matplotlib. The latter will attempt to include all data points inside the figure; it's easy to see Mathematica doesn't do that (since some parts of the line are clipped). Try scaling the matplotlib figure to that of Mathematic and see if that's consistent, e.g. `plt.axis([-0.085, 0.085, -0.05, 0.07])`  (which is essentially the inverse of your mention about plotting the Mathematica solution in a smaller field).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that and got [this](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1401785781.png) result (please press enter). What worries me is the possibility that the calculations in the python model are somehow wrong. It just seems to me that the python code produces less revolutions of the spiral in the same time interval.

Comment: With the fear that x(t) and y(t) are calculated differently in my Python code than the Mathematica code, I plotted x(t) for (t,0,10) in Python and Mathematica. And I got the following two plots: [Math](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1401786970.jpeg), [Pyth](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1401787274.png). It is clear that the functions are very different.

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake! The function f1 should have been `f1=-g(t)*yi-xi`. Also gi and g0 are not needed this way. Now the function x and the parametric plots are like the Mathematica results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `t` as your third parameter in the input vector, not as a separate parameter. The `t` in `f(z,t)` is never used; instead, you use `z[2]`, which will not equal the range of `t` as you define before (`t=np.linspace(0,20.,1000)`). The `lambda` function for `g` won't help here: you only use it once to set a `t0`, but never after.

Simplify your code, and remove that third parameter from your input vector (as well as the lambda function). For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(z,t):
    xi = z[0]
    yi = z[1]

    f1 = -t*yi-xi
    f2 = 2*xi-yi**3
    return [f1,f2]

# Initial Conditions
x0 = 1.
y0 = 1.
#t= np.linspace(0,20.,1000)
t = np.linspace(0, 10., 100)

# Solve the ODEs
soln = odeint(f,[x0,y0],t)
x = soln[:,0]
y = soln[:,1]

ax = plt.axes()
#plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(t,x)
# Put those axes at their 0 value position
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
#plt.axis([-0.085, 0.085, -0.05, 0.07])
plt.show()
```

I have commented out the actual plot you want, and instead I'm plotting `x` versus `t`, what you have in the comments, since I feel that makes it easier to see things are correct now. The figure I get:

[image]